# Error in loading a file with a Date in format "DD/MM/YYYY"

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

**Problem**

While working with Spark SQL, null values are observed in the DATE column when trying to load the file into an external table. The date is formatted as DD/MM/YYYY. Here is the Sample dataset, code and output

**Sample Dataset**

```
UserId,LastEnDate,AppLoginMessageStartTimest,IsActive,SFlag,Daycount
A23415,14/08/2023,2023-08-14 13:20:16.148+00,Passed,0,3
A23459,15/12/2023,2023-12-15 14:21:11.686+00,Passed,1,4
A23458,14/09/2023,2023-09-14 06:50:15.375+00,Passed,0,5
```

**SPARK SQL Code for loading this file in blob storage**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempdb.SampleTable
(
UserfId STRING,
LastEnDate TimeStamp,
AppLoginMessageStartTimest TimeStamp,
IsActive STRING,
SFlag BOOLEAN,
Daycount INTEGER
)
USING csv
OPTIONS ( header 'true', firstRowAsHeader 'true', delimiter ',')
LOCATION'abfss://01raw@nzadlsndhomerawdev01.dfs.core.windows.net/samplefiles/Samplefile.csv';
```

**output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You give timestamp format in options like below.

```
timestampFormat 'dd/MM/yyyy'
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SampleTable3
(
UserfId STRING,
LastEnDate TimeStamp,
AppLoginMessageStartTimest TimeStamp,
IsActive STRING,
SFlag BOOLEAN,
Daycount INTEGER
)
USING csv
OPTIONS ( 
header 'true', 
firstRowAsHeader 'true', 
delimiter ',', 
timestampFormat 'dd/MM/yyyy')
LOCATION'abfss://<container>@<storage_acc>.dfs.core.windows.net/sample/source.csv';
```

Output:

| UserfId | LastEnDate | AppLoginMessageStartTimest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A23459 | 2023-12-15T00:00:00Z | 2023-12-15T14:21:11Z |
| A23458 | 2023-09-14T00:00:00Z | 2023-09-14T06:50:15Z |
| A23415 | 2023-08-14T00:00:00Z | 2023-08-14T13:20:16Z |

And your `SFlag` column change it from `BOOLEAN` to `INTEGER` , later you convert to boolean giving condition.